# Where is the safest place to trade? Open account? Wallet?

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core-accounts, trade

I know nothing of bitcoin and would really appreciate any help and suggestions.

Comment: Please ask one specific question per post and do prior research. Your question is too broad and unclear. Please refer to [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the country you are in there are various ways to buy bitcoin. My default recommendation for US buyers is to use Coinbase.com or check out localbitcoins.com for a face to face trade.

Comment: and how do i get a wallet?

Comment: Depends what you want in a wallet, you can use the one built into an exchange or service like coinbase, open a web wallet on a service like blockchain.info, or install some software like multi-bit, electrum, or mycelium (android)

Check out this link for more info on wallets: http://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet

Comment: One last question, I hear often that someone hacked, stole, crushed, or disappeared with certain exchanges etc. Which websites/resources are the ones I can count on for 100% reliable information?